# connecting pyspark to ignite

Tags: dataframe, jdbc, pyspark, ignite

All,

I have been struggling against PySpark and Ignite itegration for like 2 last weeks and I am at my wits' end.

I have been trying to upload a table created in pyspark to ignite.

I have been starting the script like

`spark-submit --master spark://my_host:my_port --jars $IGNITE_HOME/libs/*jar, $IGNITE_HOME/libs/optional/ignite-spark/jar, $IGNITE_HOME/libs/ignite-spring/*jar $IGNITE_HOME/libs/ignite-indexking/*jar my_python_script.py`

and `my_python_script.py` was like:

```
import pyspark
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Ignite")\
    .getOrCreate()

# create the data frame
columns = ["COL1", "COL2", "ID"]
vals = [("a", "b", 0), ("c", "d", 1)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)

df.write\
  .format("jdbc")\
  .option("driver", "org.apache.ignite.IgniteJdbcThinDriver")\
  .option("url", "jdbs:ignite:thin://my_url:my_port")\
  .option("user", "my_user")\
  .option("password", "my_password")\
  .option("dbtable", "my_table")\
  .option("mode", "overwrite")\
  .save()
```

And I keep getting errors... For the above the error is `py4j.protocol.Py4JavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.save. :java.sql.SQLException: no PRIMARY KEY defined for CREATE TABLE at org.apache.ignite.internal.jdbc.thin.JdbcThinConnection.sendRequest(JdbcThinConnection.java:750`

Can anyone please help?

My spark version is 2.4.0, python 2.7, ignite 2.7

Comment: Well, I'm not an expert using ignite, but it seems like you have to specify a primary key building your table.

Comment: @KenrySanchez The problem is that CREATE TABLE is issued by Spark. How to make it create primary keys?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you're not using the Spark-Ignite integration? JDBC *should* work but there's a better way, especially since you're already including all the right JARs.

```
df.write.format("ignite")
        .option("table","my_table")
        .option("primaryKeyFields","COL1")
        .option("config",configFile)
        .option("mode","overwrite")
        .save()
```

Also note the inclusion of the "primaryKeyFields" option. As your error message notes, the version using JDBC fails because you've not defined a primary key.

Comment: The only fact that I am not using Spark-Ignite integration is my ignorance... Is is available for Python? It seems it's there for Java/Scala, but I am using Python
What is `configFile` in your response? What that should point to?

Thank you for help!

Comment: I did not add `.options("config", configFile)` yet, but sth is moving in the right direction .

I changed `.option("primaryKeyFileds", "COL1")` to `.option("createTableOptions", "primary key (COL1)")` and now I have `Syntax error in SQL statement CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE ("COL1" TEXT, "COL2" TEXT, "ID" BIGINT) PRIMARY[*] KEY (ID)`. What SQL dialect does this fiend use?

Comment: Yes, it works with Python: https://medium.com/@sdarlington/the-trick-to-successfully-integrating-apache-ignite-and-pyspark-890e436d09ba

Comment: I think the `createTableOptions`, er, option is really for the “WITH” clause, which is use for things like defining affinity or defining the number of backup nodes.

Comment: @StephenDarlington is there a way how to use the dataframe(ex. lookup the value of a key) which I read from the ignite table inside a map function of a rdd?